# Deploying to Wildfly admin console stuck

Tags: eclipse, jboss, wildfly

Im running on the latest Mac OS. I installed wildly and it is starting up with no errors. Im trying to deploy a small enterprise application, I exported it as jar file from eclipse. Im following a online course, I double checked the code it looks exactly like in the videos.

The problem is: When I deploy from the admin console, it just tells me: Your request is being processed ... waiting more then 20 minutes, no errors not even a warning, it just won't deploy and I have no clue what is the problem....

Comment: What makes you think it's not deployed?